# How to get multiple checkbox checked value in jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

On button click, I want to  get the multiple row selected value from the `datatables`. From my below code, I only get the first row selected value.

```js
function AssignVendor() {
    var table = $(assignVendor).DataTable();
    var data = table
            .row({ selected: true })
            .data();
}
```

```html
<table id="assignVender" class="mp myTable table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="select-checkbox"></th>
                                <th>MP Name</th>
                                <th>MP Code</th>
                                <th>Vendor Name</th>
                                <th>Vendor Code</th>
                                <th>From Date</th>
                                <th>To Date</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="mp in MaintenanceZones">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{mp.MP_NAME}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.MP_CODE}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.REMARK}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.VENDORNAME}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.VENDORCODE}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.VFRDATE}}</td>
                                <td>{{mp.VTODATE}}</td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It should be `table.rows().data()` - https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data() to select values from all rows. Your code `table.row().data()` is selecting single row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    $('#assignVender').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );

function AssignVendor() {
    var table = $(assignVendor).DataTable();
    var data = table.rows('.selected').data();
}
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

To Loop through the data use the following:

```
data = table.rows('.selected').data();
data.each( function ( value, index ) {
        console.log( 'Data in index: '+index+' is: '+value );
    } );
```

Comment: when no checkbox is selected 
`data = table.rows('.selected').data(); `
`data.length` should return 0 , you can put a condition on that

Comment: display alert if length is 0 else run the loop